# C Application failure with ssl linkage

Tags: c, sockets

I am facing a problem with socket programming in C. I have an application which opens a socket using C connect function, I dont want any encryption over socket. This application also uses openssl library's functions (for some other purpose) so i have to link with lssl while compiling. Due to this linkage to lssl, the application fails. I dont know what is happening, is openssl linkage overriding C's connect or what? and is it a correct approach to use C's socket functions along with using ssl library?

Comment: No, OpenSSL does not override any C functions.  There is no problem combining OpenSSL with unencrypted connections.  The problem is something else.

Comment: some error codes or source code might help us identify the problem.

Comment: I have a client application which is compiled using -lssl. There is a server running. The client should open a socket to this server using C connect() but it fails, the C connect() returns -1. When compiling the application without -lssl (removing openssl functions), it is able to open a socket successfully.

Comment: What is the value of `errno` when `connect` returns -1? Also, what platform is this?

Comment: the errno is 101 which means network not reachable, the platform is 32 bit scientific linux. Only with -lssl this problem is happening.

Comment: Most likely, something is corrupting the address structure that you are attempting to `connect` to. Can you make the actual code available? (If only partially, everything from `socket` to `connect` would be helpful, including code that fills out any address structures.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have written the code, you can see.

Answer (score 0):

The code for opening socket till connect is as below.

```
int memfsnode_init()
{
    int sockfd, portno, n,len,i,x,y;
    long l;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    portno = METADATASERVER_PORT; //port = 5000
    char *serverip;
    serverip=(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    strncpy(serverip,"127.0.0.1",strlen("127.0.0.1"));
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serverip);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");
    return(sockfd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strncpy(serverip,"127.0.0.1",strlen("127.0.0.1"));
```

That's broken. The last parameter to `strncpy` should be the size of the buffer, not the length of the string to be copied. If it's not *greater* than the length of the string (which it's not in this case) bad things will happen. As `strncpy`'s documentation says:

> **Warning**: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem, but it is still mysterious to me that why did connect() worked while not linking with ssl? even though I was using the same strncpy statement... any idea on that?

Comment: It's very hard to understand the exact consequences of breaking the rules. It's usually not worth the effort -- the takeaway lesson is just that you must follow the rules. But if I had to guess, I'd say that without OpenSSL, you got "fresh" memory that was zero-filled by the OS, and one of those zeroes terminated your string for you. With OpenSSL, you get memory that was previously used by OpenSSL, and it didn't happen to have a zero in the right place.